# JOIN and COUNT outputting only one result

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display data from three separate tables including a count for likes on the images/signs. Currently the result array only prints one result. When I remove the count it prints all of the 5 I want.

```
$query = "
    SELECT 
        image_url, image_path, date, location, fname, lname, rating,
        COUNT(DISTINCT likes.sign_id) as 'count'

    FROM 
        signs 
        INNER JOIN users ON signs.user_id=users.user_id
        INNER JOIN likes ON (signs.sign_id=likes.sign_id) 
        WHERE location='Oslo' LIMIT 5";

$result = mysqli_query ( $db_server, $query ) or die ( "Could not find uploads" . mysqli_error ( $db_server ) );
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc ( $result ) ) {
                            print_r($row);}
```

I have tried different approaches but the issues seems to only be with the COUNT, which does count the correct amount of likes. Therefore I don't know why it wont output all the results.

Comment: Why don't you do it in PHP by using `count()` as : http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a `group by` clause :

```
    SELECT 
        image_url, image_path, date, location, fname, lname, rating,
        COUNT(DISTINCT likes.sign_id) as 'count'

    FROM 
        signs 
        INNER JOIN users ON signs.user_id=users.user_id
        INNER JOIN likes ON (signs.sign_id=likes.sign_id) 
        WHERE location='Oslo'
        GROUP BY image_url, image_path, date, location, fname, lname, rating
        LIMIT 5;
```

This will work only when all this columns are the same, if not, you need to specify which of them you want.

If you meant you just want to have a column total next to each row, then you can use a correlated query like this:

```
    SELECT 
        image_url, image_path, date, location, fname, lname, rating,
        (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT l.sign_id) FROM likes l
         WHERE signs.sign_id=l.sign_id) as `count`
    FROM 
        signs 
        INNER JOIN users ON signs.user_id=users.user_id
        INNER JOIN likes ON (signs.sign_id=likes.sign_id) 
        WHERE location='Oslo'
        LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: Thank you for the swift reply! Another tiny issue arises, I can't seem to query out images that have no likes. Is there a simple solution for this as well?

Comment: @ØyvindHjartnes Replace `INNER JOIN` with `LEFT JOIN` , it will return null instead of nothing. If you want 0 instead of null, use COALESCE(count(distinct like.sign_id),0) in addition in the select.

Comment: Alright, great. I was stuck for a few hours trying to figure this out :).

Comment: Hi again, I am now trying to order results by the count. And this doesn't seem to work ORDER BY  'count' DESC Any ideas?

Comment: Use back ticks ` and not quote marks `'` . @ØyvindHjartnes